# certificate signed by unknown authority with self-signed certificates

Tags: macos, ssl, go, rabbitmq

I'm trying to setup a development environment where TLS is enabled for RabbitMQ. So here is what I did:

1. Use `tls-gen` script to generate certificates with basic profile.
2. Configure rabbitmq to use `ca-certificate.pem`, `server-certificate.pem`, and `server-key.pem`.
3. As I'm using MacOS, I ran `sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain  testca/ca_certificate.pem` to add the CA certificate to the trusted roots
4. Within a Go program, I load the `client_certificate.pem`, and `client-key.pem` into a `tls.Config`
5. Call `amqp.DialTLS()`.

I got the following error message:

```
 err: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

which is unexpected. In step 4 above, if I add the `ca-certificate.pem` into the root CAs of the `tls.Config`, it works fine. So I'm suspecting that the addition of the root ca macOS is not right.

Can somebody review the above and point out my mistake?

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: go version go1.9 darwin/amd64

Comment: If the cert you're adding is correct, you're probably hitting https://golang.org/issue/16532. I think that is 1/2 complete, and disabling cgo should load the `System.keychain` too.  Since you're setting up your own `tls.Config`, you could also just add the ca cert to the `RootCAs` there too.